# SQL expression that fetches data from one table but have criterias involving several

Tags: sql

Let's say that I have two tables in a database: `Table1` and `Table2`.

`Table1` have the following columns:

```
Var1 | Var2
```

and `Table2` have the following columns:

```
Var3 | Var4
```

I also have a constant, `x`.

Now, I would like to write an SQL expression that includes every row in `Table1` that satisfies the following criteria:

`Var1 = x`
or `there is a row in Table2 where Var4=Var2 and where Var3=x`

How do I write this as an SQL expression?

I guess it should start with `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Var1=x` but from there, I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic element that you need is a UNION, which essentially appends one result set to another.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Var1=x

UNION

SELECT *
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Var2 = Table2.Var4
WHERE Table1.Var1 <> x -- this is to avoid dups of rows that satisfy both cases
  AND Table2.Var3 = x
```

Comment: I guess this is correct for the question I actually posted. However, in reality, the two tables I have differ (among other things regarding number of columns), so the `union` statement doesn't work.

Comment: You can either select common columns between the the two tables or select IDs only, save it in a temporary table, then do a secondary select on each table to get the rows by ID.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
where t1.id=1 and t2.year='2012' and t3.user='me'
and t1.id = t2.id
```

or

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
 inner join table2 t2
on t1.var2=t2.Var4
where t2.Var3 = x
```

I think the second one is more likely to fit your needs.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand this answer. What is t1? table1? What is table1 then?

Comment: @Speldosa t1 is an alias to table name table1 (it is kind of an abbreviation, rather than using table1 every time. **t1.id** means **table1.id**)

Comment: The operation you need is **join**. Union can meet your needs in the limitations of your specific conditions. Maybe you should paste both table structures., some sample data as source and result.